# Does the Android Transformer API optimize the input video to be streamable over the internet (faststart)?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, exoplayer, android-media3

Does anyone know if the Android Transformer API optimize the input video to be streamable over the internet (by moving the moov atom to the front)? Is there a setting you can set for that?

All I could find in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/transformer/getting-started#start) was this:

> The input can be of any container format supported by ExoPlayer, but
> the output is always an MP4 file.

Considering the output is always an MP4, it is probably optimized for web streaming, but I would like to know for sure if that is the default case or if it is something you need to set before running the transformer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: currently it doesn't support Fast Start.

Longer answer: The Media3 Transformer has 2 implementations of Muxer:

1. `DefaultMuxer` uses `FrameworkMuxer` which uses the system `MPEG4Writer` (part of the Stagefright engine).
2. `InAppMuxer` uses their own implementation called `Mp4Muxer`.

Both Muxers write the `moov` atom last (after `mdat`).

You can verify this using a tool such as `AtomicParsley`.

```
AtomicParsley transformer-output.mp4 -T
Atom ftyp @ 0 of size: 28, ends @ 28
Atom mdat @ 28 of size: 11822589 (^), ends @ 11822617
             (^)denotes a 64-bit atom length
Atom moov @ 11822617 of size: 4424, ends @ 11827041
     Atom mvhd @ 11822625 of size: 108, ends @ 11822733
     Atom meta @ 11822733 of size: 177, ends @ 11822910
         Atom  @ 11822745 of size: 4296, ends @ 11827041
```

The Media3 team is aware of the issue:
https://github.com/androidx/media/issues/727

Comment: That is unfortunate, considering most people using this API will probably be uploading their videos to be streamed online. Do you have any suggestions on how to make an .mp4 file Fast Start on Android?

Comment: There's a library that some people recommend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573824/move-moov-atom-to-front-of-video-natively-in-android